# response на extJs

Tags: json, extjs

Работаю на extJs, результат Ajax запроса возвращает Json

```
[
  {
    "id": 8159,
    "leaf": true,
    "base": false
  }
]
```

как мне отсюда достать значение id?

до этого пробовал так:

```
success : function(response) {
var answ = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
if (answ.id > 0) {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Операция выполнено', answ.desc);
} else {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Операция не выполнено', answ.desc);
}
```

}

так он возвращает undefined

Comment: А вы уже как-нибудь пытались его достать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
console.log("id=",obj[0].id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если json - строка, воспользуйтесь `JSON.parse`, далее `obj[0].id`